# Configure grafana-loki output plugin

Tags: fluent-bit, grafana-loki, fluent-plugin-grafana-loki

i'm trying to use the grafana-loki output plugin in fluent-bit but it seems impossible to configure with tls.

i had a **working** configuration running with the loki plugin like this :

```
[OUTPUT]
Name loki
Match *
Host my-collector-url-for-loki
Port 443
Http_User m-user
Http_Passwd some-token-value
Labels job=fluentbit
auto_kubernetes_labels on
Tls On
Tls.verify On
```

but the problem with this output plugin was that the logs are not showing correctly on grafana, i think a filter or parser needs to be configured for it or maybe the plugin is just meant for loki not grafana/loki, i just don't know and i got tired of trying to figure out why. So i switched to the grafana-loki plugin and the logs looked perfect on grafana but i only had it working without authentication.

this is my setup with grafana-loki output plugin

```
[Output]
Name grafana-loki
Match *
Url https://url-to-my-logs-collector
TenantID ""
BatchWait 1
BatchSize 1048576
Labels {job="test-fluent-bit"}
RemoveKeys kubernetes,stream
AutoKubernetesLabels false
LabelMapPath /fluent-bit/etc/labelmap.json
LineFormat json
LogLevel warn
# everything prior to this line is working successfully
# trying to set authentication here "this part doesn't work"
Tls On
Tls.verify On
Http_User m-user
Http_Passwd some-token-value
```

Problem with this setup, i always get a 403 forbidden http status. I'm having trouble figuring out how to set authentication on this plugin. Does anyone have a working configuration for this type of setup?

Comment: have you sorted this? having the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication worked for me using this plugin using like below:

```
[Output]
    Name grafana-loki
    Match *
    Url https://${user_loki}:${pass_loki}@lurl-to-my-logs-collector
    BatchWait 1s
    BatchSize 102400
    TenantID ""
    (...)
```

`TLS`, `http.user` and `http.passwd` options are not support, as far as I could understand, by this plugin.